# How to combine two words in a long string into one & find their associated sentence?

Tags: python, string, text, nltk

Given a very long string -

"Given the large category of plants, the **split ratio** was determined to be 88.4. However, we're not sure if the **split ratio** was consistent across all subcategories or just a calculated average. If however, it deviated, it would be nonetheless, quite strange.

The words - **split ratio**. In the output, I want them to appear as **split-ratio** (as a single word) and I also only want to retain sentences where these words occur. So in this case, only the first two sentences.

Is this possible?

Comment: *"I also only want to retain sentences where these words occur."* In that case, can those two appear independently anywhere in a sentence?

Comment: Not really, they always appear together. In fact, once I combine them, then I want to retain only the sentences that contain "split-ratio".

Comment: can you share your desired output clearly ? @RahulDev

Comment: Hi Rahul, if any of the answers here was helpful, please consider accepting by clicking tick on the left of the answer. This helps the community identify the helpful solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` in a list comprehension:

```
s = """Given the large category of plants, the split ratio was 
       determined to be 88.4. However, we're not sure 
       if the split ratio was consistent across all subcategories 
       or just a calculated average. If however, it deviated, 
       it would be nonetheless, quite strange."""

print('. '.join([x.replace('split ratio', 'split-ratio') for x in s.split('. ') if 'split ratio' in x]) + '.')
```

will print out only lines that contain `'split ratio'` with each of them converted to `'split-ratio'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since python is in the tag line I expect you want it in that language right? And to be clear a simple find-replace in a normal text editor isn't going to solve this issue I suppose, you need actual logic to apply onto something.

I would have to stop and look up python for a bit. But in any language the easiest way I can think of is to just parse out the file/stream and make the changes as you go. Read in the stream and look for the pattern you want a match for = "split ratio" - regardless, as you are reading in the stream, write out a new one that favors your changes. But do it in the block size (or string length) of the pattern you are matching.

When you find true for the pattern you are constantly comparing, stop. Don't output that string, instead output the one you want to replace it with into the new target stream/file.

However, a search for python search and replace algorithm gives me this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Someone did the hard work for you already. Love that super high level programming language that leaves folks in the dark as to what is actually happening. Oh well.

Enjoy.

atomkey.